# Fastest way to write every pixel on the screen/window in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I want to algorithmically specify every pixel on the screen (full screen) or window to paint in a Java application. I want to do an animation this way.

So, for each pixel, I'll run some type of calculation to determine what color it should be. I'll do this every frame for every pixel.

What is the highest performance (capable of highest frames per second) way to do that?

I understand graphics cards are programmable, but I'd like to stick with just coding in Java for this. If there is a straightforward way to code the algorithms in Java such that they run on the graphics card, that would be great, but I want a solution that does not involve another programming language (which I think OpenCL or such does).

Comment: Could you do the calculations on the graphics card?

Comment: Definitely draw to a buffer before applying the whole image to the screen. From experience with this same thing, I can say that it saves a lot of time. There may be, and probably are, other things you can do to make it even faster, but I don't know them.

Comment: If it was straightforward to code up the calculations on the graphics card, that would be great. But my understanding is that it requires something like OpenCL or shader programming, something like that, and is rather complicated. So, if there is an easy way to do it all on the graphics card, I would like to know, otherwise... I'll change the question to say "all java".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this type of animations before using a the [`PixelGrabber`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) and [`MemoryImageSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html) combination. Here you have some documentation and [samples](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/awt/ch12_04.htm).

Thats the technique with best performance I know. You usually work in the pixel array (do the frame animation transformations) and then render the pixels in the resulting image (Don't need to invoque `getPixel/setPixel` methods to set individual pixels, which, in old times, was a great optimization).

Don't have any code sample of my own right now, but I can provide one later if you're interested in using this.

As a side note, old editions of the book [Java The Complete Reference](http://books.google.co.ve/books/about/Java_The_Complete_Reference_Seventh_Edit.html?id=C_l2R8ZSPMoC&redir_esc=y) make plenty use of this techique for image manipulation examples.